# I added checkbox in flutter but it can't clickable

Tags: flutter, checkbox

I added checkbox but it can't click please tell me reason

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9ksl.png)

Comment: Place your boolean variable above build(). You can't update isChecked boolean inside build()

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare variables outside the build method. Else on every state-changes, it will get the same value being inside the method.

```dart
bool isChecked = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){

 return ...
```

More about [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)